# If else statement depending on textfield (swif3)

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, textfield, is-empty

I would like my code to simply display a label if and only if there is text in the textfiled if there is no text the label should be hidden. Thats it. My code below does not do what I have described above.

```
   import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var txtfield: UITextField!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
appear()

  }
   func appear() {

if (txtfield.text?.isEmpty)! {
    label.isHidden = true

}
else {
    label.isHidden = false
}}}
```

Comment: How does the textfield gets filled? programmatically from another view controller? Or the user writes something on it?

Comment: @Pochi the user writes something on it.

Comment: so you want the label to appear/disappear AFTER the user writes something on this view controller. Right?

Comment: @Pochi yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below .

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        textChanged(txtField)
    }

    func textChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField.text == ""
        {
            textField.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            textField.isHidden = false
        }
        print("Hello")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)),for: .allEvents)
    }
```

- `func textChanged` will hide your `textField` if it is empty .
- Adding it to `viewWillAppear` will check `textField` at the screen appearing time .
- In `viewDidLoad` target (`textChanged`) is added to `textField` for every events .

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because the check is only being performed ONCE when the View Controller is loaded.

What you have to do is run the appear() function every time the user finishes editing the text field.

So just set the delegate of your text view to this view controller and implement this function:

```
optional func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618628-textviewdidendediting

Then just call the appear() inside it.

Edit: Text Field version

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting

Comment: I am using a textfield not textview.

Comment: Then use the textfield version, it's the same.

Comment: or else keep one button and call `appear()` function on button click